# oracle coherence client throw pof related error "unknown type: coherence.util.UUID"

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I have a task which involves connecting to a remote coherence cluster and retrieve the metrics info of objects in its caches.

I succeeded in establishing the connection, and correctly retrieve the size of the designated cache, however, when I tried to iterate the entrySet it throws errors.

I have this JVM options:

```
"-Dtangosol.pof.config=application-pof-config.xml"
```

application-pof-config.xml has something like:

```
<include>another-pof-config.xml</include>
```

insides "another-pof-config.xml" is a bunch of real <user-type> tags

There are two parts of issues when I tried to tackle it:

First it complains "another-pof-config.xml" is not found - while the file is indeed NOT in the classpath, it's in a jar which is in the classpath;

Then I bypassed the original "application-pof.config.xml" and use:

```
"-Dtangosol.pof.config=another-pof-config.xml"
```

instead, I got an error like:

```
Unknown user type: coherence.util.UUID
```

I figure that the "UUID" type is in coherence.jar and it's in the classpath, so I was puzzled what this error means exactly? Looks like it's found but can't be understood.

Answer (score 0):

never mind - it's my stupid mistake: there is a tag in the xml is not close with

```
</...>
```